# Dll loading order

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll

If i have global variable in A.dll, that depends on global variable in B.dll , is it guaranteed that B.dll will be loaded before A.dll? I made two sample dll projects in Visual Studio, and link A.dll with B.dll , and it seems, that B.dll is loaded first.So is this behavior guaranteed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is guaranteed by the OS, because otherwise it would be impossible to write proper dll-loading code. In particular, if `A.dll` imports `B.dll`, then when the dynamic linker attempts to load `A.dll`, it will see that dependency and load `B.dll` into the process first.

Comment: On msdn says that I can't call functions from User, Shell, and COM dlls in my DllMain. If it is guaranteed that User, Shell, and COM dlls will be loaded before mine ( like in the example above where B.dll is loaded before A.dll), then it should not be error to call these system dlls in DllMain of my dll. Sure I am not understanding something :( What I a missing ?

Comment: That's not the reason you can't call those functions. The real motivation is more complicated: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx

Comment: It IS possible & legal to create dll's with circular dependencies. In which case all bets are off wrt load order.