# Why doesn't virtualenv create DLLs folder?

Tags: python, windows, dll, pydev, virtualenv

I'm wondering what's the reason virtualenv doesn't create `DLLs` folder the same way it creates `Lib` and `Scripts` ones?

The question came to me when I had the following problem with PyDev;
I set one of my virtualenvs as a Python interpreter and everything was ok with one exception. I've kept getting warnings about unresolved import for all imports from `select` module. This is because `select` module, unlike most others, is present only in the DLLs folder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I investigated this subject a little more. I started from *techtonik's* statement - *The answer is simple - nobody implemented it.* This however, begs another question - why nobody implemented it? I suspect the answer is because it works. This leads to yet another question - why does it work?

The reason everything works without `DLLs` folder being copied into virtualenv is that

- Python searches `sys.path` to find any dll it needs
- `sys.path` after virtualenv's activation contains path to the original `DLLs` folder

The first statement can be simply tested by removing path to `DLLs` folder from `sys.path` and trying to import `select` module (this module needs `select.pyd` file from `DLLs` folder) which then fails.

In the comment you say *I'd like to keep Python module's DLLs in the virtual environment along with the Python code.* That's possible by simply copying `DLLs` folder into virtualenv. The reason this works is that `sys.path` after virtualenv's activation contains also path to the `DLLs` folder inside virtualenv (although there's no such folder being created when creating virtualenv). This path is placed before path to the original `DLLs` folder which means it's being searched first and thus overrides the original `DLLs` folder.

I posted question titled [DLLs folder on Windows](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.general/724833) at Python's mailing list.

Comment: "sys.path after virtualenv's activation contains path to the original DLLs folder"
I didn't `activate` my env, and it also contains path to original DLLs folder in `sys.path`. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: *(...) `sys.path` after virtualenv's activation contains **also** path to the `DLLs` folder inside virtualenv (...)* Without virtualenv being activated `sys.path` contains path to the *DLLs* folder from Python's installation. After virtualenv has been activated `sys.path` contains **both** paths — to virtualenv's specific *DLLs* folder and also to the *DLLs* folder from Python's installation.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simple - nobody implemented it. When I created the patch to copy pythonXX.dll into virtualenv environment - I was solving a different problem:

When Python is installed system-wide - the python.exe binary that is copied to virtualenv is always able to find its pythonXX.dll, because this .dll is available from Windows\System32. If Python is installed only for current user - the pythonXX.dll is placed into PythonXX dir where original python.exe is located. So the problem I was solving is to fix virtualenvs created with Python installed for current user. It was quite a problem to dig up all this stuff.

Back to the question. I don't really know how this pythonXX.dll finds its DLLs modules - this is a question to Python developers, but I suspect that it doesn't find them. The reason why I didn't fix this issue while fixing [issue #87](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/87) is that my code probably never used modules from this DLLs directory.

Answer (score 3):

IMO there are more reasons for that:

- Security: In some environments, the policy is to deny executing/loading stuff from random locations, in an attempt to prevent security breaches. Thus,
- The somewhat famous [DLL](http://tech-eureka.blogspot.be/2009/08/windows-dll-load-order.html) [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382222/dll-loading-order) [order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which prevents malicious dlls to be loaded :). See also [here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/87)

HTH,

Comment: The question is about Windows where there's no policy that would prevent loading dlls from any specific location.

Comment: Even if there's no explicit policy in place, the DLL load order is still valid (and you'd need to add it to the list). Also, given the multitude of options, virtualenv would need to cope with multiple variants, which may not be feasible.

Comment: DLL load order is irrelevant here because as I wrote in my answer Python searches for dlls in folders placed in `sys.path`.